# How do I make a tangent recursion?

Tags: recursion

This is what I have but I don't know what I'm doing wrong:
I'm suppose to write a continued fraction of tangent too.

```
double Tangent(int x)
{
    if (x==1)
    {
       return 6;
    }
    else
    {
       return x/Tangent((1)-(x*x))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the math is OK  (is `tan(1)` supposed to equal 6??), you may need to change `if (x==1)` to something like `if (fabs(x-1) < 1E-4)`, since exact comparison of a double-precision number may place an unrealistic requirement for convergence.  To see what is going on, I'd add a `printf` statement in the function, and watch the output to see if it converges.